# pg_dump on Windows puts extraneous characters in the dump file?

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL v13.x, Windows 2019 Server

I'm using the following command either from a Powershell or command window

```
> pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -W --format custom --file my_db_dump.sql my_db
(p/w prompted and entered)
```

The dump is created successfully. However it's full of extraneous non-printable control-sequence characters, e.g., `^A^N^@^X^@^@^@....`, you name it. Post processing, e.g., `dos2unix`, `:set ff=unix`, `:%!col -xb` doesn't eliminate the characters. Is there a switch in `pg_dump` to control this? I didn't see it in the [pg_dump documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the custom format which is not plain SQL. It has structure and some compression. If you want plain SQL that is also available as a format.

Comment: Yep thanks. From the link I gave, "This format is also compressed by default." Hence, the funny characters.

Comment: Even if you added `-Z 0` (no compression) you would still get funny characters as the output file is in binary form.